# "Lock" Excel Workbook for VSTO in C#

Tags: c#, locking, vsto, excel

Is there a way to lock an Excel workbook in such a way that you cannot select any cells and/or change any of the workbook's information?  Basically when my program is in export mode, I don't want the user to be able to change data or select any cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this way : [Locking worksheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkcs53f3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Code snippet given by the MSDN :

```
Globals.Sheet1.Protect(getPasswordFromUser, 
missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, 
missing, missing, missing, missing, true, missing, missing);
```

You should be able to do the same without using the Globals.Sheet1, because the MSDN assumes you have such a sheet. Doing it programatically should be possible.

Edit : Locking the Workbook itself, but you seem to want to lock both the WorkBook and the worksheet :
[Workbook locking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7czw9wzs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
this.Protect(getPasswordFromUser, missing, missing);
```

The password is optionnal :

> The Protect and Unprotect methods allow you to protect a Microsoft Office Excel 2003 workbook so that users cannot add or delete worksheets, and to unprotect the workbook again. You can optionally specify a password, indicate whether you want the structure protected (so users cannot move sheets around), and indicate whether you want the workbook's windows protected.
>
> Protecting a workbook does not stop users from editing cells. To protect the data, you must protect the worksheets. For more information, see How to: Protect Worksheets.

here is another link [Common tasks in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/syyd7czh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: .NET 4.0 makes it so you don't need all the "missings"...get with the times...geesh! :) +1 though

Comment: i looked at this, but i didn't think i could prevent the user from activating a cell - which apparently you can with this.

Comment: yeah, all the params in [] are optional. And concerning the cell activation, I dont know. If you really need to prevent the activation of cells, you might want to go with a thread specific hook, or else maybe try a workaround with the VSTO, by looping. But im really not sure of the result in the end.